# Not getting Adx reports using doubleclick publisher DFP API

Tags: google-dfp

I am switching from ADX seller API to DoubleClick publisher API because ADX seller API is doing to die in couple of months.

Here got code from below link.

https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib/blob/master/examples/Dfp/v201802/ReportService/RunInventoryReport.php

Everything i got an report with below single line in CSV file.

Dimension.AD_UNIT_NAME,Dimension.AD_UNIT_ID,Column.AD_EXCHANGE_AD_REQUESTS,Column.AD_EXCHANGE_ESTIMATED_REVENUE,Column.AD_EXCHANGE_CLICKS

This is comma separated Dimension and column name.

However i can get list of all ad Units and Placement through same API and same credential.

What am i missing?